# emulating an installed win10 on a raid0 volume from ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, hard-drive, raid, qemu, emulation

first of all setup:

- 2 ssd in raid0 set up from my motherboard (intel z97 + i5 4690k + amd
  r9 390); on this raid0 i have installed a copy of win10 64bit with
  his own bootloader
- 1 wd hdd with a copy of Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS 64-bit with his grup
  bootloader
- 1 other big hdd with only files and something installed from win10
- other details http://pastebin.com/iqVM89Cf

what i would like to do is run the copy of windows 10 already installed on the raid from linux using a emulator, possibly qemu or a open surce one.

is it possible to make my windows copy run like it is booting on it's own from a virtualized environment while in linux?

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You will probably get better expertise on [AskUbuntu](http://askubuntu.com).

Answer (score 0):

With QEMU or KVM you can pass through a block device by editing the xml config file for that vm. For example:

```
<disk type='block' device='disk'>
    <source dev='/dev/disk/by-id/ata-Corsair_CSSD-F120GB2_1109650632000461003B' />
    <target dev='hdc' bus='virtio' />
</disk>
```

You can read more about adding block devices to guests [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Virtualization_Administration_Guide/sect-Virtualization-Adding_storage_devices_to_guests-Adding_hard_drives_and_other_block_devices_to_a_guest.html). 
Keep in mind Windows will detect that the hardware has been changed and may not like it. I have read that people have had issues with this configuration that require a reinstall of Windows within the vm.